# the specified deps.json does not exist angular2 asp.net core application.

Tags: entity-framework, angular, asp.net-core

I have a database I am trying to scaffold into my angular 2 .net core application. I upgraded to .net core 1.1 followed most steps but I am getting the error the specified deps.json does not exist. This is my project.json

```
  {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "HannaOilAndGas2"
  }
}
```

this is how I am trying to scaffold my database

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver,1433;Initial Catalog=database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data
```

this connection string works because I have built regular models and accessed them with this connection string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on this line

"

```
frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

I needed to change to

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```