# VS 2017 specified deps.json does not exist asp.net core application.

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ef-database-first

I have a database I am trying to scaffold and my question is nearly identical to question in [the specified deps.json does not exist angular2 asp.net core application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617855/the-specified-deps-json-does-not-exist-angular2-asp-net-core-application) However mine is using VS 2017 and it's a regular MVC project - not Angular.

There is no project.json in VS2017 as most of the functionality is now in cs.proj. Do I need to make a change of some sort in cs.proj or is there some other approach to this error?  At this point it's a fresh project (started in VS 2017) and I'm following the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db - except I'm using my own database.

Thanks.

Comment: Once I ran dotnet restore and ef migrations add Initial then scaffolding worked